# Nuget push fails with 417 (Expectation Failed) from remote server

Tags: nuget, httprequest

When I run a "nuget push" command from the command line, the upload fails and nuget dies with the following error:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 417 (Expectation Failed).`

Nuget's documentation doesn't give any indication what this could mean.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://plexperiments.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/visual-studio/) suggests it's an issue with an intermediate proxy server interfering with the PUT request that nuget.exe is attempting.

> Http status 417 is caused when your proxy server does not support 100-continue. As a result, the client request does not get a response from the server indicating the client should POST data.

Check your system proxy settings and verify that either the proxy being used supports 100-continue, or that the proxy is bypassed for the servers Nuget is connecting to.

Nuget itself can be configured with proxy settings that will override the system settings. See the [Nuget configuration documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file#config-section), specifically regarding proxies.